# Having `vike` app deployed on Netlify with `+onBeforeRender` for a SPA dynamic page leads to an error

Tags: vite, preact

I'm using a `vike` + `preact` setup and host my app on Netlify.

Having `+onBeforeRender` for a SPA page makes the app crash. Static/prerendered routes don't have this issues. The contents of the file don't matter. The function can be just empty.

What would be the way to try to debug/fix this?